# How to arrange stack of DIV tags in funnel shape?

Tags: asp.net, css, html

I am working on a asp.net web application.

I have a stack of DIV tags..which inturn contains link buttons.

I would like to display these in a tunerl form...as shown below.

Could somebody suggest me a good method for the same.

**I need these dynamically**

```
   |            |
   |            |
   \           /
    \         /
      \      /
       \    /
        |   |
```

Can I use Polygon as a container ?

I mean define a ploygon....and divide the space in polygon depending upon the div tags available...and fill the polgon with DIV tags.

Comment: You may want to take a look at something like slantastic: http://meyerweb.com/eric/css/edge/slantastic/demo2.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Websites are built on the [box model](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html) so it's impossible to have a "polygon-shaped div" if that's what you're looking for.  If you want the `div` tags to be on the outside, you could however use `float: left;` and `float: right;` on various rows of divs with a shorter width container each time.  If you want the `div` tags themselves to be the funnel-shape, then you just have a single div for each row and have the width change as they go further down the page.